# How do I the roots of a quadratic function given certain conditions?

Tags: roots

Let's say I have an equation $x^2+2(1-m)x+6m-11=0$, how would I go about finding for what values of m are both roots located in the segment -1<x<1?

Comment: Is it as simple as finding out when both f(-1) & f(1) are bigger than 0 and then finding out when and if the solution set of that intersects with $Discriminant>0$  ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the quadratic formula,

$x=\dfrac{-2(1-m)\pm\sqrt{4(1-m)^2-4(6m-11)}}{2}$

$=-(1-m)\pm\sqrt{(1-m)^2-(6m-11)}$

$=-(1-m)\pm\sqrt{m^2-8m+12}$

**First, by examining the determinant, we have**

$m^2-8m+12\geq0$

$(m-4)^2-4\geq0$

$m\geq6\text{ or }m\leq2\ \ldots(1)$

**Then, regarding the range of $x$,**

$-1<x<1$

$-1<-(1-m)\pm\sqrt{m^2-8m+12}<1$

$-m<\pm\sqrt{m^2-8m+12}<2-m$

Since a positive square root is non-negative and a negative square root is non-positive, we require that

$\begin{cases}
-m\leq0 \\
2-m\geq0
\end{cases}$

Hence, $0\leq m\leq2\ \ldots(2)$.

**For positive square root,**

$0<+\sqrt{m^2-8m+12}<2-m$

$0\leq m^2-8m+12<(2-m)^2$

$m^2-8m+12<4-4m+m^2$

$4m>8$

$m>2\ \ldots(3)$

**For negative square root,**

$-m<-\sqrt{m^2-8m+12}\leq0$

$0\leq m^2-8m+12<m^2$

$-8m+12<0$

$m>\frac{3}{2}\ \ldots(4)$

**Conclusion**

Now, we have the compound inequalities:

$\begin{cases}
m\geq6 \text{ or } m\leq2\ \ldots(1)\\
0\leq m\leq2\ \ldots(2)\\
m>2\ \ldots(3)\\
m>\frac{3}{2}\ \ldots(4)\\
\end{cases}$

Since (2) & (3) contradict each other, there are **no solutions for $m$**.

---

Regarding your suggestion of making $f(1),f(-1)>0$ followed by testing the determinant constraint, I was quite amazed at first glance until I gave it a second thought. There is a flaw in this method.

Substituting $m=6$, we have

$f(x)=x^2-10x+25$

$f(1)=16>0$ and $f(-1)=36>0$, whereas the root is $x=5$.

[image]

That means, if you only guarantee $f(1),f(-1)>0$, hoping that the two roots are between them, you fail to rule out the possibility that $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$ are on the same side of the roots, and hence the roots fall out of range.

Comment: What interpretation did you give to the comments following the original posting?

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I've just noticed the comment after posting it. Let me supplement my advice of his suggestion.

Comment: @HirofumiRyo, thanks! I see there is flaw in my original method. If we add one more final condition, that the x value of the vertex must be in the range -1<x<1, do we get rid of the flaw?

Comment: Yes. I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the quadratic polynomial into "vertex form" gives us
$$ x^2 \ + \ 2(1 \ - \ m)·x \ + \ (6m \ - \ 11) \ \ = \ \ ( \ x \ - \ [m - 1] \ )^2 \ + \  (6m \ - \ 11) \ + \ (m \ - \ 1)^2 $$
$$ = \ \ ( \ x \ - \ [m - 1] \ )^2 \ + \  (6m \ - \ 11) \ - \ (m \ - \ 1)^2 \ \ = \ \ (x \ - \ [m - 1])^2 \ - \ (m^2 - 8m + 12)     $$
$$ = \ \ (x \ - \ [m - 1])^2 \ - \ (m - 2)·(m - 6)  \ \ .   $$

As with **Hirofumi Ryo**'s method using the discriminant of the polynomial, we see that there are no zeroes for $ \ (m - 2)·(m - 6) \ < \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ 2 \ < \ m \ < \ 6 \ \ . \ $  Further, we can reject $ \ m \ \ge \ 6 \ \ , \ $ as this places the vertex of the represented parabola at $ \ x \ \ge \ 5 \ \ , \ $ so certainly at least one of the zeroes is greater than or equal to $ \ 5 \ \ . \ $

But $ \ m \ \le \ 2 \ $ **must also** be rejected.  With $ \ m \ = \ 2 \ \ , \ $ the vertex lies at $ \ x \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ $ so while the polynomial has a "double zero" at $ \ x \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ $ this is not located in the interval $ \ (-1 \ , \ 1) \ \ . \ $  Decreasing $ \ m \ $ brings at most one zero into the specified interval, *but not both*.  For example, at $ \ m \ = \ \frac{11}{6} \ \ , \ $ the polynomial becomes $ \ x^2 - \frac53·x \ \ , \ $ with its zeroes at $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ and $ \ x \ = \ \frac53 \ \ . \ $  For $ \ m \ = \ \frac32 \ \ , \ $ the polynomial is $ \ x^2 - x - 2 $ $ = \ (x + 1)·(x - 2) \ \ , \ $ with zeroes at $ \ x \ = \ -1 \ $ and $ \ x \ = \ +2 \ \ . \ $  So as the vertex "moves downward and to the left", the larger of the two zeroes *remains* greater than or equal to $ \ +1 \ \ , \ $ never entering the interval in question; meanwhile, the smaller zero is less than  $ \ -1 \ $ for $ \ m \ < \ \frac32 \ \ . \ $  Thus we find that there is **no value** of $ \ m \ $ which can place  both zeroes in $ \ (-1 \ , \ 1) \ \ . $

[With a little additional work, we can show that the larger zero $ \  (m \ - 1) + \sqrt{m^2-8m+12} $ $ = \ (m \ - 1) + \sqrt{(m -4)^2 - 4} \ $ asymptotically approaches $  \ +3 \ \ : $
$$ \lim_{m \ \rightarrow \ -\infty} \ (m \ - 1) + \sqrt{(m -4)^2 - 4} \ \ = \ \ (m \ - \ 1) \ - \ (m \ -  \ 4) \ \ = \ \ 3 \ \ . \ ]  $$